# Outputting inequality with $e^x$

Tags: reference-request, inequality, exponential-function

I many books I can find inequality which estimates $e$:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \lt e \lt \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$

I am wondering if correct is also to write:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx} \lt e^x \lt \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{x(n+1)}$$
or maybe I can just raise the parties to the power?

Or maybe is any similiar inequality for $e^x$ like this?

Comment: Care must be taken. How do you define a quantity like $a^x$ when $x$ is not an integer?

Comment: No- even for positive $a$ and a real number $x$, how do you define $a^x$? The answer to this question depends upon what's your definition.

Comment: @voldemort yes, but let's not be pedantic here...

Comment: he means what does it mean to take something to the power of $\pi$... while taking $x^2 = xx$, $x^3= xxx$, it is not clear what $x^\pi$ is without some discussion, but I get the feeling this is not the explanation you were looking for...

Comment: @Mandlbrot: Really? and what does perform the multiplication say $\pi$ times mean? I am curious.

Answer (score 0):

yes for $x>0$, because taking something to the power of $x$ is a strictly increasing function.

http://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf

To address your comment: here are some useful inequalities about the e, it is on the left of the first page.

Comment: @Mandlbrot see edit.

Comment: @Mandlbrot if you are happy, with accept the answer by pressing tick (and also do the same to your other questions, that way people are more willing to help you in the future), thank you

Comment: @Mandlbrot it is correct. and you mean $\lim_n(1+1/n)^{nx}$, anyhow you should accept your other answers anyway... i was not just self adveritising